# Why is setuptools so slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I have a one python library but and it is in wheel 40 MB. But, it takes more then 12 hours to make the wheel file.

setuptools get stuck here:

```
copying server\views\generic\edit.py -> build\lib\server\views\generic
copying server\views\generic\list.py -> build\lib\server\views\generic
copying server\views\generic\__init__.py -> build\lib\server\views\generic
creating build\lib\server\views\templates
copying server\views\templates\__init__.py -> build\lib\server\views\templates
```

here it is stuck for most of the time but it still uses my processor.

I was just curious why it takes so long to make the Wheel file to post it on pypi.

Comment: We can't diagnose why your big build takes so long, since we have access to 0% of the code and the build configuration.

Comment: The setup.py in the [project](https://github.com/Matthijs990/os_sys-pypi) you linked (and then deleted the link to) seems pretty weird and buggy. The Github repository seems to be missing components you have on your own machine (like whatever `data_types.txt` is), and it's not clear whether the stuff that is on Github matches what you have locally. I'm inclined to think your problem is due to bugs in your setup script.

Comment: i can remember there was a bug that made it slow try: python -m pip install -U setuptools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to build a package your could to

clean the cache:

```
find . | grep -E "(/__pycache__$|\.pyc$|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf
```

Clean dist and build:

```
rm -rf dist/
rm -rf build/
```

In your `setup.py` add only the package that you need or exclude that you don't need:

```
packages=find_namespace_packages(exclude=("test", "doc", "dist", "build"))
```